# How to select radio from dynamic table row in Nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nightwatch.js

i am trying to select the radio button from row with same value as column text in dynamic table in Nightwatch.js.
but, all the xpaths examined in the loop will be the last loop xpath.

How can i get xpath for each loop counter?

i have the code

trList.html(tr is dynamic and may be added even after 0005)

```
<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">TITLE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">check box</td>
                    <td>No.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checkradio"></td>
                    <td>0001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checkradio"></td>
                    <td>0002</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checkradio">
                    </td>
                    <td>0003</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checkradio">
                    </td>
                    <td>0004</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checkradio">
                    </td>
                    <td>0005</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

testNightwatch.js

```
var url = "trList.html";

//check box targetNo
var targetNo = "0003";
var elementCount;
var parentPath = "/html/body/table/tbody/";
module.exports = {

  '@disabled': false,

  'tr dynamic selection' : function (client) {
    client
      .url(url)
      .elements('xpath', parentPath +'tr',
        function(result){
          elementCount = Object.keys(result.value).length;
          console.log(elementCount);
          console.log("data is " + String(Number(elementCount)-2) + " rows");
          for(var i=3; i<=elementCount; i++ ){
              //rows xpath
              var xpath = parentPath + "tr[" + i + "]/";
              client
                .useXpath()
                .getText(xpath + "td[2]",
                    function(result){
                        console.log("current row is " + result.value);
                        console.log("current path is [" + xpath + "td[1]/input]");
                        if(targetNo === result.value){
                            console.log("target checkBOX!");
                            client
                                .useXpath()
                                .click(xpath + "td[1]/input");
                        }
                    });
          }
      })
      .pause(1000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

output Console

```
data is 5 rows
current row is 0001
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0002
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0003
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
target checkBOX!
current row is 0004
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0005
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
```

Desired output console

```
data is 5 rows
current row is 0001
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0002
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0003
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/input]
target checkBOX!
current row is 0004
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input]
current row is 0005
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have to add a waitForElementPresent() and include your path. What's happening now is likely that the code, being asynchronous, is advancing to it's endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A selector could be obtained with the second argument of waitForElementPresent ().
I was able to dynamically obtain xpath using it

testNightwatch.js

```
  'tr dynamic selection' : function (client) {
    client
      .url(url)
      .elements('xpath', parentPath +'tr',
        function(result){
          elementCount = Object.keys(result.value).length;
          console.log("data is " + String(Number(elementCount)-2) + " rows");

          for(var i=3; i<=elementCount; i++ ){
              //rows xpath
              var xpath = parentPath + "tr[" + i + "]/";
              client
                .useXpath()
                .waitForElementPresent(xpath + "td[2]", function(result,xpath){
                    result.value.map(function(element, err){
                        client.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'innerText', function(res){
                        console.log("current row is " + res.value);
                        console.log("current path is [" + xpath.element.selector.slice(0,29) + "td[1]/input]");
                            if(res.value === targetNo){
                                console.log("target checkBOX!");
                                client.useXpath().click(xpath.element.selector.slice(0,29) + "td[1]/input");
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
          }
      })
      .pause(1000)
      .end();
  }
```

output Console

```
data is 5 rows
√ Element </html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]> was present after 20 milliseconds.
current row is 0001
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input]
√ Element </html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]> was present after 16 milliseconds.
current row is 0002
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input]
√ Element </html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]> was present after 16 milliseconds.
current row is 0003
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/input]
target checkBOX!
√ Element </html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]> was present after 37 milliseconds.
current row is 0004
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input]
√ Element </html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]> was present after 20 milliseconds.
current row is 0005
current path is [/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/input]

OK. 5 assertions passed. (1.768s)

OK. 5  total assertions passed. (3.865s)
```